# How to efficiently merge a large number of files into a single file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have hundreds of millions of small plain-text files in a folder. I want to merge them into a single large file with some processing. What is the fastest way to do it? Currently, I have the following code:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER="some-folder"
TARGET="target-file"
FILES=`find $FOLDER -name "*.txt"`
for f in $FILES
  do
    cat $f | ./some-processing-script.pl >> $TARGET
  done
```

While this works well for a small number of files. When it is actually used to process the large set of files, it becomes very slow after the target file is greater than 25G or so. I think is is because of `cat ... >> $TARGET`, which has to scan through the entire current target file for each new input file, before attaching new content to the end of the target.

I know how to use java or python to solve this. I am just curious if i can solve this in bash. Thanks.

Comment: There's no "scan through the current target", the file is open in append mode.

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect the output of the loop instead:

```
for f in $FILES
  do
    ./some-processing-script.pl < $f
  done >> $TARGET
```

(I've also eliminated a [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).)

Comment: When dealing with "hundreds of millions" of files, this will create hundreds of millions of Perl processes, which will take a very long time.  This is significantly better than the example code in the question, because removing the UUOC halves the number of processes created, but solutions using `xargs` or `find ... -exec ... +` will do a lot better.  Moving the redirection is unlikely to make a significant difference.  Note also that `$FILES` will contain gigabytes of data, which might cause performance problems due to swapping.

Answer (score 4):

What's your definition of 'merge'?  Does your Perl script take file name arguments?  Do your file names ever contain spaces or other awkward characers?

Assuming your script does not take command line arguments, you could do one of:

```
cat $(find $FOLDER -name "*.txt") | ./some-processing-script.pl >$TARGET
```

Or, if there are too many files for a single command line, then:

```
find $FOLDER -name "*.txt" -print | xargs cat | ./some-processing-script.pl > $TARGET
```

Or, if you've got spaces in names and a modern enough `find` (POSIX 2008 compliant):

```
find $FOLDER -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} + | ./some-processing-script.pl > $TARGET
```

If you really want to append to the target file always, then replace the `>` with `>>`.  In these examples, `cat` is being used to concatenate multiple files, which is a proper use of `cat`.  The UUOC (Useless Use of `cat`) award goes with using `cat` to process a single file at a time when I/O redirection would do the job instead.

If you're in charge of the Perl script, you should modify it to be a 'standard filter', a program that reads the files specified on the command line or standard input if no files are specified.  You can then eliminate the `cat`:

```
 ./some-processing-script.pl $(find $FOLDER -name "*.txt") >$TARGET

find $FOLDER -name "*.txt" -print | xargs ./some-processing-script.pl > $TARGET

find $FOLDER -name "*.txt" -exec ./some-processing-script.pl {} + > $TARGET
```

Of these options, the last is the one I'd use, assuming the Perl script accepts or can be modified to accept file names on the command line.  If the Perl script can't (be made to) handle command line arguments, then I'd use the third command with the `cat` and pipe.  But this illustrates why you should design programs (Perl scripts) to behave like standard Unix filters when possible; it means you can combine them more efficiently into command pipelines.

Comment: `cat $(find $FOLDER -name "*.txt")` that's terrible!

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the `perl` script, I recommend to use :

```
shopt -s globstar # enable bash4 recursion with **
./some-processing-script.pl **/*.txt > big_file.txt
```

The `perl` script :

```
while (<>) {
    # processing the content
    print;
}
```

You can do too :

```
find $FOLDER -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} + |
    ./some-processing-script.pl > big_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this bash line of code on 23k files in a directory, I think the speed is acceptable.

```
for f in path/*.txt; do cat "${f}" >> merged.txt; done
```

Reference: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/148505-concatenation-large-number-files.html

Answer (score -1):

Use the command line switches:

```
perl -pe '{}' abc_file_qualifiier_*.csv > merged_file.csv
```

`-p` assumes an input loop around your script. Lines are printed.
`-e` used to enter one line of the script
`'{}'` an empty script